# Remove all instances of specific item from a combobox in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am populating a `ComboBox` with a list of all the running processes on a system. However, I want to be able to remove all the system processes and general noise from the list.

This is the code I am trying to use:

```
try
{
    var allProc = Process.GetProcesses();

    foreach (var p in allProc)
        comboBox1.Items.Add(p.ProcessName);

    comboBox1.Sorted = true;
    comboBox1.Items.Remove("svchost");
}
```

However I think all it is doing is removing a single instance of the `svchost` from the list, when in reality there are many.

How would I remove all of a specific item from the `ComboBox`?

Comment: Lets start from why do you add it in the first place?

Comment: So the user can select which process they would like to restart: The user selects an application, enters an email address saves the settings. Then the next time the program runs it will shut the selected program down, restart it, take a screenshot. attach that to an email and email it to the entered email address. Then the program closes it self. 

It a work project, but i am just trying to refine it a bit.

Comment: @JamesMorrish, WPF or WinForms?

Comment: It's a WinForms app

Comment: Why dont you check the p.ProcessName before adding it to the combobox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I don't see why you add those processes name to the combobox, if the next line you remove them. Isn't it simpler to just not add them?

```
 var allProc = Process.GetProcesses().Where(p=>p.ProcessName != "svchost");
 foreach (var p in allProc) comboBox1.Items.Add(p.ProcessName);
```

Second, if you do want to remove item after you've added them, find all the items and remove them with a loop:

```
foreach (string item in cb.Items.Cast<string>().Where(name => name == "svchost"))
{
    cb.Items.Remove(item);
}
```

Comment: I added them like this becuase i didnt know i could not add them at all :)

Comment: Also, instead of `foreach` and `Add()` you can use `AddRange()` - `comboBox1.Items.AddRange(allProc.Select(p => p.ProcessName));`

Comment: @RomaDoskoch perfect, even better!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
for (int i = 0; i < comboBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    string st = comboBox1.Items[i].ToString();
    if (st == "svchost")
    {               
        comboBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i);
        i--;                    
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, is there anyway i could specify multiple items to remove with this code?

Comment: yes just add a new condition in the if statement like `if (st == "svchost" || st == "whatever")`

Comment: Ahhh, i see i just tried to use: if (st == "svchost" || "whatever") and it didnt like it. 

But this makes sense. Thanks.